# KendoUI grid local paging not working with remote data?

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use Kendo-UI to manage a grid on a page, however I'm having a hard time with the following specific set-up:

The data is fetched from a remote source, however, I would like to do paging on the client side, not on the server side.

The whole problem can easily be summarized with the following jsfiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/dimodi/4eNu4/

When `serverPaging: true`, everything works as expected, but when `serverPaging: false`, no entries are show after the first page.

Comment: For anyone interested, this bug seems to be fixed in later releases of KendoUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined a dataBound event function that does not return any data.

Define your function as:

```
function resizeGrid(d) {
    var gridElement = $("#grid");
    var dataArea = gridElement.find(".k-grid-content");
    var newHeight = gridElement.parent().innerHeight() - 2;
    var diff = gridElement.innerHeight() - dataArea.innerHeight();
    gridElement.height(newHeight);
    dataArea.height(newHeight - diff);
    return d;
}
```

I've added an argument `d` that I return at the end of your processing.

Updated fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4eNu4/253/

Comment: Splendid, thank you very much for your time and input. Would you please mind elaborating a bit on why the return statement is necessary?

Answer (score -1):

All you really have to do is remove the `serverPaging: true` config option. Then just set a `pageSize: 10` in the schema and then add `pageable: true` to the config of the grid to allow for client side paging.

Updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4eNu4/247/ hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: No pages beyond page one are functional in your _jsfiddle_ example, which is exactly the problem explained in the original question. This is not a working solution, sadly.